Does anyone know what all the decryption questions are for?
Ref:  Find the encryption and decryption keys
This is one of many such questions that pop up every few days.  Someone's gone to the effort of posting this which takes time (unless it's a bot).  No one's going to even attempt it and it will be closed /deleted within a  few hours.  There's also no outbound link to some movie or product so it can't be advertising.  They also all appear to be of the same style and length.
Is it a bullying or some sort of attempt at cruelty (I'm  a cynic who's read way too much psychology).  Set an impossible question for the geeks and watch them squirm kind of?
So why do they appear so frequently? What's their point?

Standard theory is (AFAICT) that people come across ciphertext in CTFs, homework, videogames or whatever and then just ask here. Usually they have no clue, which is why they see "oh a crypto forum, I bet they are all geniuses and can solve this in an instant"


So why do they appear so frequently? What's their point?

There seems to be a correlation between the timing of these questions and when school is in session. Maybe just a coincidence, but my guess is that they appear so frequently because a lot of undergraduate crypto courses follow a similar structure. So I'm assuming their point is to get help with homework.

I think we have also seen CTFs and video games as sources.
